# xsl:choose check all xsl:when conditions

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is there any way not to leave `<choose>` after first `<when>` match but continue check else  conditions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe it's a no. As the spec says:

> The content of the first, and only the first, xsl:when element whose
>   test is true is instantiated. If no xsl:when is true, the content of
>   the xsl:otherwise element is instantiated. If no xsl:when element is
>   true, and no xsl:otherwise element is present, nothing is created.

from: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose

you can't make it fall through other conditions like that. just convert it into a set of `<xsl:if>` following one another if you need a fall through

**UPDATE**. Here's a quote from the O'Reilly's XSLT book ( http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch04_02.htm ):

> The C, C++, and Java switch statement is roughly equivalent to the
>    element. The one exception is that procedural languages
>   tend to use fallthrough processing. In other words, if a branch of the
>   switch statement evaluates to true, the runtime executes everything
>   until it encounters a break statement, even if some of that code is
>   part of other branches. The  element doesn't work that
>   way. If a given  evaluates to true, only the statements
>   inside that  are evaluated

Comment: Thnx for fast answer, yes, will have to use `<xsl:if>`